# Swiftui onFocus is deprecated in xcode 13.5 beta, how to solve?

Tags: swiftui

```
.onFocus({ isFocused in

     variable = false
           })
```

This code is not working anymore since update to 13.5 beta.
How can i achieve the same, so if a textfield is focused then....do something

Comment: See `focused`, `FocusState`, `FocusValue` ... depending on your needs